# Rename a directory after extracting zip archive uploaded by user

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-os

I'm trying to rename the directory after extracting it in a temporary directory.The archive upload by user.
What I mean, User will upload a **.tar** OR **.zip**  file then I will make a temporary directory and extract user's file into that directory, now I want to rename it extracted directory which is inside temporary directory.

Here's what I have tried:
In my **views.py**

```
    if form.is_valid():
       deployment = TarWithoutDocker()
       deployment.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
       deployment.user = request.user
       deployment.archive = form.cleaned_data['archive']
       deployment.save()
       tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
       saved_umask = os.umask(0o077)
       path = os.path.join(tmpdir)
       arpath = deployment.archive.path
       patoolib.extract_archive(arpath, outdir=path)
       os.rename(path + '/' + deployment.archive.name[:-4], 'archive')
       print(path+'/'+deployment.archive.name[:-4])
```

But when I print `print(path+'/'+deployment.archive.name[:-4])` it should print users' file name without .zip OR .tar extension.

See what it prints out:

> **archives/frequent_sign_in_form-web_Free18-07-2017_1046736122_9aAbZpD.zip**
>   patool: Extracting /Users/abdul/Documents/IGui/media/archives/frequent_sign_in_form-web_Free18-07-2017_1046736122_9aAbZpD.zip ...
>   patool: ... /Users/abdul/Documents/IGui/media/archives/frequent_sign_in_form-web_Free18-07-2017_1046736122_9aAbZpD.zip extracted to `/var/folders/g2/8fzl8mjj5xxfqdfvrl7v3q_40000gn/T/tmpj8gzegdq'.
>   [28/Jul/2017 05:16:08] "POST /user/deployment/new/awd HTTP/1.1" 302 0
>   [28/Jul/2017 05:16:08] "GET /user/deployment/new/awd HTTP/1.1" 200 15289

Comment: please can you fix the indentation in the code ? not sure what the if is including..

Comment: now I have updated that!